# How to put actionable icon in adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I trying to find how to put actionable icons on Adaptive cards to use with Microsoft Teams. The aim to replace button with image icon(with all button behavior).

Comment: Could you please try using selectAction property on the image to add action to the image. Please try this out in the [Adaptive card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).

Answer (score 1):

in Adaptive Cards 1.2 any image can have an action, see this example:

```
                        {
                        "type": "Image",
                        "style": "Person",
                        "url": "${creator.profileImage}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "selectAction": {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "url": "https://www.google.de"
                        }
```

The action can be submit, openUrl etc like other actions. You can find the option in the designer aswell to try it.